# I want to see the code or script change in git which triggered the build in jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

I am using jenkins for automatic build when change occur in git repository.I want to see the code or script change in git which triggered the build in jenkins. Is there any plugin for this.

Answer (score 0):

There is one for your requirement:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/All+Changes+Plugin

-Jyotsna

Comment: I already added that plugin but it shows an error like


`A problem occurred while processing the request. Please check our bug tracker to see if a similar problem has already been reported. If it is already reported, please vote and put a comment on it to let us gauge the impact of the problem. If you think this is a new issue, please file a new issue. When you file an issue, make sure to add the entire stack trace, along with the version of Jenkins and relevant plugins. The users list might be also useful in understanding what has happened.

Stack trace`

Comment: Try this one : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Changes+Since+Last+Success+Plugin